# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaLiveDebug

Tags: android, retrolambda

I'm using this apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda' in my project.
but sometimes then I build my project, android studio will show me this error.
And I don't know how to do but just clean my project and it will be ok.
but it waste time to clean. Anybody know how to solve this problem.

```
:app:processLiveDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateLiveDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileLiveDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileRetrolambdaLiveDebug FAILED
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaLiveDebug'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe''

Answer (score 0):

I get this exact same error when building after doing a "Clean Project" in Android Studio. Building again without any change allows it to succeed.